# create a browser to display dynamic web pages inside a java application

Tags: java, browser

I want to create a web browser inside a java application. I tried using JEditorPane but it only displays a static HTML page.Can anyone help me with this please

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a Java browser library. Have a look at JxBrowser, JBrowser, JavaFX and SWT Browser Widget.

If you want your browser to render client-side scripting languages such as JavaScript, have a look at the available JavaScript engines, some of which are written in Java: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines